# Python USB sometimes not recognized

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, usb

I have code that is supposed to check whether a certain file exists in a USB stick that is plugged in by the user when prompted. The issue is that the script sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails on the exact same machine with the same USB stick with the batch file required. My manager cannot sign this script off unless I can make the script consistent enough.

I have checks in my code for drives up to H so I've ruled out that the USB device may be in a different drive since my code will account for it.

Here is the part of my code which checks for the file (without the other drives since it is redundant):

```
rcode = mbox(u'Attention!', u'Please insert burn-in USB stick.', 0x41)

# Run burn-in if ok
if rcode == 1:
    time.sleep(20)   # Wait for USB to be recognized
    if os.path.isfile(r'D:\burnin.bat'):
        os.chdir('D:')
        rcode = call('burnin.bat > NUL', shell = True)
        if rcode != 0:
            print 'Failed.'
            log.write('FAIL - Failed to run burn-in test\r\n'
                      '       Error: {}\r\n'.format(rcode))
        else:
            print 'Done.'
            log.write('OK   - Burn-in test completed successfully\r\n')

            #Check SMART parameters
            dataOne = diskOne(log)
            smartTest(log, dataOne)
            print 'Disk One Done'
            dataTwo = diskTwo(log)
            smartTest(log, dataTwo)
            print 'Disk Two Done'

    elif os.path.isfile(r'E:\burnin.bat'):
        os.chdir('E:')
        rcode = call('burnin.bat > NUL', shell = True)
        if rcode != 0:
            print 'Failed.'

            log.write('FAIL - Failed to run burn-in test\r\n'
                      '       Error: {}\r\n'.format(rcode))
        else:
            print 'Done.'
            log.write('OK   - Burn-in test completed successfully\r\n')

            #Check SMART parameters
            dataOne = diskOne(log)
            smartTest(log, dataOne)
            print 'Disk One Done'
            dataTwo = diskTwo(log)
            smartTest(log, dataTwo)
            print 'Disk Two Done'
```

Previously the sleep statement only waited 10 seconds so I moved it up to 20 seconds. Also, there were some SMART parameter checks right before the file check which I removed to see if that was messing with my script. Despite these changes my code still does not pass consistently enough for release to our production team.

I am wondering if there is a better way to find this file and make my script more consistent. I remember seeing this inconsistency issue when I was doing web automation with Ruby.

Comment: Without more debugging results, the root cause is hard to pinpoint. You should consider debugging this by writing down the results for the following questions: "is the USB-drive detected" (a better module for your detection scheme is provided by [pyusb](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst) by the way), "is the file found", "is the `call` successfully executed". Bottom line is: be more specific when you say "it sometimes fails".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the extremely late update. There is no bug in the code. I determined it was a hardware issue. The USB keys I was using were cheap and poor quality. I've advised the production team to use different USBs and since have not encountered this failure.